# Visual Studio UI Testing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ui-testing

I have done some extravagant web searching for a solution to no avail.

I am working with a UI tester written by a man who is no longer with the company.

Currently it is hanging up on opening the browser for testing the website.

I have no idea what I'm doing.

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "ie";
```

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: which windows version? do you have ie installed?

Comment: I'm currently using Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what the issue is.  I can't run it directly.  I have to pass it to MSTest.exe with arguments.

If you don't know where MSTest.exe is, here is where mine is, and most likely yours.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
```